# Trying to save current data in an NSMutableArray on exit, and load it on launch

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using an `NSMutableArray` to store data from my `UITableView`, and I'd like to store the data in `NSUserDefaults` on the application `didEnterBackground` as well as `willTerminate`. Here's how I'm doing this so far:

Delegate:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later. 
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

    EXViewController *main = [[EXViewController alloc] init];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:main.data forKey:@"dataKey"];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

    EXViewController *main = [[EXViewController alloc] init];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:main.data forKey:@"dataKey"];
}
```

`main.data` is an `NSMutableArray`.

I forgot how to do this, being the fact that I haven't worked with table views in some time. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Full delegate code (.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class EXViewController;

@interface EXAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate> {

EXViewController *_main;
NSString *title;
}

// Data to be added
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *title;

// Default properties
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) EXViewController *viewController;

@end
```

And (.m):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
_main = [[EXViewController alloc] init];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.viewController = [[EXViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EXViewController" bundle:nil];

// Create navigation controller
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are allocating and initializing a new instance of EXViewController everytime - you should probably reference the single instance in your app delegate and then save/restore that data.

**EDIT**

```
// In your AppDelegate.m - a lot of code ommitted
// NOTE: make sure that self.viewController points to self->_main
// This must be in the @implementation block
@synthesize viewController = _main;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // NOTE: Notice the removal of the _main = ...
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    // NOTE: This is the only view controller you should reference.
    self.viewController = [[EXViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EXViewController" bundle:nil];

    // Create navigation controller
    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];

    self.window.rootViewController = nav;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
     // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.viewController.data forKey:@"dataKey"];
}

// You will also need to restore it when needed
```

Comment: I tried using: `@property (strong, nonatomic) EXViewController *viewController;` instead of creating a new instance, but it still won't work. Tried: `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:viewController.data forKey:@"dataKey"];`

Comment: I just edited the post to show how you might use your `@property`.  You need to maintain a reference to the actual view controller that is storing data.  When you do an alloc/init you are creating a NEW controller with it's own data (presumably an empty NSMutableArray).

Comment: Show your updated code in the question please.  You just need to be sure to reference the existing EXViewController instance.

Comment: I just saw your edits - I have updated mine.  Make sure you are not alloc/init any other EXViewControllers.

Answer (score -1):

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.data forKey:@"dataKey"];

[[NSUserDefaults standartUserDefaults] syncronize];

}
```

Where data is a property.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you probably don't mean to alloc/init a new view controller there.

Comment: How can I access without instantiating a new view controller?

Comment: @RyanCohen using properties maybe, save your controller in some property on app start

Comment: I don't get why so many people think that it's mandatory to call `synchronize` every time a change is made in the user defaults. That is handled automatically, it's just a waste of cycles. Also, creating a new view controller in `applicationWillTerminate:` makes no sense whatsoever, aside from the fact that `applicationWillTerminate:` will almost never be called nowadays because of multi-tasking (you want to use `applicationDidEnterBackground:`).

Comment: Okay, tried it, doesn't work. Just synthesized the property that was already created in the AppDelegate.h class.

Comment: @omz, from docs "Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, **if your application is about to exit**) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes."

Comment: Yeah, @omz. Synchronize is a waste of a one-liner really.

Comment: @omz I agree that the `synthesize` method is over used but this is actually the one place you do want it just incase the app is killed in the background before the system automatically persists the latest changes.

Comment: @AndrewShmig which .h & .m? Delegate or VC?

Comment: @rmaddy The user defaults are synchronized automatically when the app goes to the background (which would always happen before being killed in the background). I think that comment in the docs refers to calling `exit()` (which you shouldn't do on iOS anyway), not a regular termination of the app.

Comment: @omz I find no mention that user defaults are automatically synced when the app enters the background. Do you have a link for that?

Comment: @rmaddy I can't find documentation on this, but in 5 years of doing iOS development, I haven't used `synchronize` once, and I never had a problem with defaults not being persisted. I also just checked with a symbolic breakpoint, and it looks like `synchronize` is indeed always called when suspending or terminating an app (from `-[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:]`).

Answer (score -1):

Saving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// saving an NSString
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// saving an NSInteger
[prefs setInteger:42 forKey:@"integerKey"];

// saving a Double
[prefs setDouble:3.1415 forKey:@"doubleKey"];

// saving a Float
[prefs setFloat:1.2345678 forKey:@"floatKey"];

// This is suggested to synch prefs, but is not needed (I didn't put it in my tut)
[prefs synchronize];

Retrieving

NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

// getting an NSString
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

// getting an NSInteger
NSInteger myInt = [prefs integerForKey:@"integerKey"];

// getting an Float
float myFloat = [prefs floatForKey:@"floatKey"];